# Cannot cancel a BackgroundWorker procss

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, cancellation

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that includes a class `ExcelOutput`, used to output various data to a workbook, and I should mention straight away that `bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True` is set.

At each stage of the output I'm checking for errors in `ExcelOutput` using `Try/Catch`, and if necessary displaying an error (using a function called `ErroReport()`.

In conjunction with the error message, I want to cancel the `BackgroundWorker` to avoid further errors. To that end I have added the `OutputWorker` property to the `ExcelOutput` class and I set that to be a copy of my `BackgroundWorker` in the `bw_DoWork()` method.

However, the cancellation carried out in `ExcelOutput.ErroReport()` is not working, and I don't know why.

Note that I've tested the value of `bw.CancellationPending` and it is set to `True` after an error. I've also tested that the `If` condition following is working by showing a message box, and that also works. For some reason it seems as though the `Exit Sub` command is ignored though.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is how the `bw_DoWork()` function from the `BackgroundWorker` class is set up -

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object,
                      ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim Excel As New ExcelOutput  ' Create a new instance of the ExcelOutput class
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer = 4    ' Set the first output row

    '** Include a copy of the OutputWorker in the ExcelOutput (so that the OutputWorker can be cancelled)
    Excel.OutputWorker = Me

    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Excel.Prepare()
    End If

    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("General", Headers, Data, 4)
    End If

    ' More stuff here...

End Sub
```

Here is how the `ErrorReport()` function from the `ExcelOutput` class is set up -

```
Private Sub ErrorReport(ByVal Ex As Exception,
                        Optional ByVal CustomMessage As String = "")

    Call Me.ResetRange()    ' Destroy the 'Range' object
    Dim ErrorMessage As String = "Message: " & Ex.Message ' Set the default message
    If CustomMessage <> "" Then ErrorMessage = CustomMessage & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Ex.Message
    Dim Result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage,
                                            "An Error Has Occured",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                            MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

    '** Close the workbook (if it's open) and stop the OutputWorker *'
    Try
        Call Me.WB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        If Me.OutputWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
            Me.OutputWorker.CancelAsync()
        End If
    Catch
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add the DoWorkEventsArgs as parameter to your ErrorReport function.

```
Private Sub ErrorReport(ByVal Ex As Exception,
                    Optional ByVal CustomMessage As String = "",
                    ByVal e As DoWorkEventsArgs)

Call Me.WB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    If e.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
        e.CancelAsync()
    End If
```

You'll be able to cancel the Backgroundworker.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same result this way too.